# Aliens come to the solar system to speak with our sun

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

70's era (I think) science fiction story.  Aliens come to the solar system to speak with our sun.  They believe stars are sentient.  First contact story but aliens are not much interested in humanity.  Think the aliens were described as looking similar to small giraffes.

Comment: This sounds familiar. Any more info, like what was the resolution?

Comment: Did the Sun answer?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

["If the Stars Are Gods"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41291), a 1974 novelette by [Gordon Eklund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_Eklund) and [Gregory Benford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_Benford).

**Aliens come to the solar system to speak with our sun. They believe stars are sentient.**

> "We left our homeworld a great many of your years ago. I cannot tell you exactly when, for reasons I'm certain you can understand, but I will reveal that it was more than a century ago. In that time we have visited nine stars. The ones we would visit were chosen for us beforehand. Our priests—our leaders—determined the stars that were within our reach and also able to help us in our quest. You see, we have journeyed here to ask certain questions."
>
> "Questions of the stars?"
>
> "Yes, of course. The questions we have are questions only a star may answer."

**Think the aliens were described as looking similar to small giraffes.**

> There was one Earth animal that did resemble these creatures, and this was why Reynolds felt happy and relieved. The aliens were sufficiently alien, yes. And they were surely not men. But neither did they resemble blobs or wolves or sharks or snakes. They were giraffes. Nice, kind, friendly, pleasant, smiling, silent giraffes. There were some differences, of course. The aliens' skin was a rainbow collage of pastel purples, greens, reds and yellows, similar in its random design to the colorfully painted walls. Their trunks stood higher off the ground, their necks were stouter than a normal giraffe. They did not have tails. Nor hooves. Instead, at the bottom of each of their four legs, they had five blunt short fingers and a single wide thick offsetting thumb.

Comment: That's it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlanRIggs You're welcome!